# How to use getEventBus method in SAPUI5

Tags: events, sapui5

I am trying to understand `getEventBus()`. Can somebody provide a tutorial or best example where and how we can implement `getEventBus()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the EventBus in SAPUI5 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187748/what-is-the-eventbus-in-sapui5-for)

Answer (score 19):

I´ve provided an example to answer another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842857/1969374).

To put it in a nutshell, you can call `sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus()` to get access to the EventBus instance. As it comes from the core it´s the same across all of your views/controllers. The EventBus provides you with the publish/subscribe functionality. This for example enables you to publish an event in Controller A and notify the subscribed Controller B. A simple example largely from my other answer:

**Subscribing to the EventBus:**

```
var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
eventBus.subscribe("channel1", "event1", this.handleEvent1, this);
```

Of course you can name your channel and events as you wish. The third parameter indicates the function, that will be called in case of published events. The last paramter is the scope, 'this' will point to in the given function.

Your `handleEvent1` function could look like this:

```
handleEvent1 : function(channel, event, data) {
    var customData = data.customData
}
```

**Publishing events to the EventBus:**

```
var customData = {}  // anything you eventually want to pass
var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();

eventBus.publish("channel1", "event1", 
    {
        customData: customData
    }
);
```

If you have more questions about it let me know so I´ll extend it.

Comment: yes can you please elaborate same.

Comment: What exactly do you want to be more elaborated? Do you have certain questions?

Comment: Hi @TimGerlach I followed your approach for pub/sub in SapUI5. But my case is a bit different i.e. I want to publish from Application A and want to listen in Application B. In this scenario, it does not works.
If one view is sub-view of other it works.

Comment: Hi @RusheelJain, please create a new question for that.

Comment: Hi @TimGerlach, what if I want to return some data from 'event1'? Can I access it from eventBus.publish ?