# how to modularise or extend component in sapui5

Tags: sapui5, uicomponents

I am trying to build a mobile application and i am using navigation and routing for switching between my views.
since my app has many view using single component becomes bulky.So i want to modularise that by loading additional routes to my component when needed.

I went through the [developer guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_UI5_Developer_Guide_for_SAP_HANA_en.pdf) which shows how to extend the components (page no.306-308),by doing so i was able to get data of my parent component but could not add additional routes to it..

So i thought of having two different components,please see the attachment in the link [my SCN posting](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3646692) 
problem is i cannot directly navigate to the view corresponding to my subComponent since every time the browser loads my application it starts main component and not my subComponent  and my main component cannot recognize the routes of my subComponent.Hence bookmarking doesn't work.
Is there any way how to communicate between components???

my goal is to modularise my component...
It would be a great help if any one knows or understands my problem and solution for it...
Also suggest if there is any problems in my application structure and any changes to be made...

I am sorry for my long question

Regards,
Ajaay krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To communicate between components you can use events, in your case you can also create a function that will act as a service that your sub-component registers to and in the callback receives the routes.

To understand UI5 events you can see this reply 
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382988/how-to-use-geteventbus-method-in-sapui5)

Regards,Saar

Comment: Thanks saar,can u please explain it in brief how to do??,ie,where should i publish n subscribe??