# Call views controls from another view to get data in application

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to call a control of the master view from the detail view controller. If I do it like this I am able to get the list data

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("application-Test-url-component---master--list")
```

if i do it like this I am not able to get the list

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("list").
```

Is this the correct way to call if any version changes

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("application-Test-url-component---master--list")
```

Please provide suggestions or any links.

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187748/what-is-the-eventbus-in-sapui5-for
just write a data provider methode in the controller the data is from

Comment: in bTob, there is almost no use case for this. Usually you can handle things over routing. Why would you like to do this?

Comment: Thank you bkr using router i able to get the data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use the `byId(...)` method on the `Core`, it's bad practice and not a good habit to get into.

For your interest, the reason your first line of code does find the relevant UI control, but the second line does not, is because the `Core` is shared across all applications in the Fiori Launchpad. This means that all Control IDs are prefixed with the application namespace, and because your second line of code does not contain the application namespace it therefore does not find the Control.

As for how to correctly get the List data from that Control from elsewhere, simply get the bound data from the same model path you're binding that Control to. For example, if the Master list is bound to `{/Products}` then you get the same data by `this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/Products")`. This assumes that your data model is shared across the application however. I would recommend that you read the UI5 documentation and understand more about MVC architecture, because the UI Controls should just surface the data which is stored in the underlying Model(s) and that is where the data should be.