# How to access model of parent view in UI5

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

The view is declared this way:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.sap.my.app.controller.Edit"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:bpa="com.sap.my.app.control"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  height="100%">
  <mvc:XMLView viewName="com.sap.my.app.view.AttachmentPreview"/>
</mvc:View>
```

How can I access the model defined in the `Edit` controller within the `AttachmentPrevie` controller?

The `AttachmentPreview` will be reused inside multiple other views. Not only in `Edit` view.

Comment: What do the controllers do that the sub-controller needs to access data from its parent controller? Have you considered [using `EventBus`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186706/5846045) instead? On the other hand, models are usually propagated to children automatically. Your sub-controller should be able to access the parent model (not in `onInit` though). Either way, we need more information to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Make you model global by declaring it in manifest.json file if possible or inside Component.js file

Comment: Ok :/ Is there not another solution which can better scale accross ? What if I want to display the attachmentPreviewer multiple times on the same screen....

Comment: I don’t see any impacts if you need to do that. Could you please elaborate your concern? Thanks

Comment: Let's say you have an email client and you can open two emails at once. Then you have two attachmentPreviewer but only one place in the global model...

Comment: I still don't see the problem. A model is basically just a storage for data (plain old javascript objects). Your `AttachmentPreview` can read this data. Open your `AttachmentPreview` twice just means reading the data twice. Don't see any scaling problems.

Comment: This feels like a global state management solution, but in many cases, the states (model) should not be global. Let's say I have a subdomain of Task, and its UI contains a TaskList page and a TaskDetail page. Why would I want to expose this Task model to other pages if these are the only two pages using it? Or let's say there're a few local UI-related properties or dynamic properties generated on the fly being set as JsonModel in the parent view, and I want to pass that down to its direct child views. These properties should not be global. Making everything global breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply refer to the parent view with the method `getParent()` in the child view e.g. `this.getView().getParent().getModel()`. Please do make sure that the view itself is already attached or else the getParent would return null.