# SAPUI5 Execution of parent application functions from the content of ComponentContainer

Tags: sapui5

I am building a SAPUI5 page, which will actually be one page with many tabs, and the tabs will each be based on a default component with the option to change it to a special purpose component.

I am thinking of using ComponentContainer here.

So it will be possible that we have 4 tabs: 3 based on component C1 - default, and 1 based on component C2 - special.

Is it possible to call from the controller of component C1 / C2 a function in the controller of the main APP (the one with tabs)?

Is it better to build a solution on calling a function in controller C1 / C2 from a separately created library?

The assumption is that a set of default functions will be prepared, but component can override the function.

So C1 will execute e.g. the standard function X () and Z (), and C2 is to overwrite the function X () and perform the standard function Z ().

The solution can be expanded, so copying the functions to each new component is omitted - it will be difficult to modify in the future.

The components will contain dynamically generated content based on the configuration in ERP.

Comment: Have you considered using `EventBus` instead? --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186706/5846045 might be helpful in your case.

Comment: You mean to run functions in Main App raising event in one of the Components? 
If component have no override method then raise event and catch it in main app.
It seems like a good idea, I'll think about it, thank's.

Comment: Did using the `EventBus` help?