# Is there a way to get a callback as soon as the component is loaded inside the bootstrap implementation?

Tags: sapui5

I'm using `data-sap-ui-onInit="module:my/custom/bootstrap"` who's implementation ends with `sap.ui.require(['sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport']`.

Is there a way to get a callback as soon as the component is loaded inside the bootstrap implementation? I would like get a reference to the component object once it's initialised.

Comment: I guess you could publish an event from the `Component.js` content and subscribe to that event in your `bootstrap.js` using [`EventBus` from the core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46186706/5846045). Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Acceptable for sure, but the ideal solution wouldn't require adding specific code in `Component.js`. Are there any events published by default in the lifecycle of the UI5 component?

Comment: The `sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer` does provide the [event `componentCreated`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer#events/Summary) but then, same as `Component`, you'd have to get a reference to the created `ComponentContainer` instance which is not given in `bootstrap.js`  - unless you access the container or component via `byId` or [`sap/ui/core/Component.registry.*`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Component.registry).

Comment: I looked at `componentCreated` before, but couldn't figure out how to attach that from the `<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap">`. I thought there is no way for me to use it as it's the `ComponentSupport` which creates the `ComponentContainer`.

Comment: Documentation is now enhanced with a sample of event registration in the `div` element: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/pull/87

Comment: Unfortunately, registering global event handlers via the HTML attributes, such as `data-component-created` and `data-component-failed`, has now become deprecated since https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d6cc88938a6479e7ba8b7ab00b15e27832c47d8b (UI5 1.120). If you want to keep using `sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport`, please consider creating an enhancement request on https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues by describing your scenario and possibly other use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without touching the `Component.js` content, if you can control both the initial HTML document (here: `index.html`) and the JS file assigned to `data-sap-ui-oninit` (here: `myBootstrap.js`) you can attach a handler to the [`ComponentContainer`'s events such as `componentCreated` or `componentFailed`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer#events) like this:

### In `index.html`:

```html
<head ...>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="<...>resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-async="true"
    data-sap-ui-resourceRoots='{ "my.demo": "./" }'
    data-sap-ui-oninit="module:my/demo/myBootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-...="..."
  ></script>
</head>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
  <!-- Only in UI5 1.x as registering a global event handler in HTML 
  like below is deprecated since UI5 1.120 and removed in UI5 2.x -->
  <div data-sap-ui-component
    data-id="myRootComponentContainer"
    data-name="my.demo"
    data-component-created="onMyComponentCreated"
    data-height="100%"
    data-settings='{ "id": "myRootComponent" }'
    data-...="..."
  ></div>
</body>
```

### In `myBootstrap.js`:

```js
// ...
globalThis.onMyComponentCreated = function(event) {
  const myCreatedComponent = event.getParameter("component");
  // ...
};

// === With UI5 1.x ===
sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"]); // will register onMyComponentCreated only in UI5 1.x
// ====================

// === With UI5 2.x ===
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer", // has to be created manually for this case only in UI5 2.x
], ComponentContainer => new ComponentContainer({
  id: "myRootComponentContainer",
  name: "my.demo",
  componentCreated: globalThis.onMyComponentCreated, // or an anonymous function
  height: "100%",
  settings: { id: "myRootComponent" },
  // Settings that sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport applies by default:
  lifecycle: "Container", // enum sap.ui.core.ComponentLifecycle
  autoPrefixId: true,
  manifest: true,
}).placeAt("content"));
// =======================
```

Here, the handler name "`onMyComponentCreated`" is just a sample name. Make sure to create a name that would not cause a name collision in the global scope, or assign an anonymous function when creating a `ComponentContainer` manually.

---

Regarding the `data-component-created` syntax:

> As HTML is case-insensitive, in order to define a property with upper-case characters, you have to **"escape" them with a dash character**. (From the API reference: [`sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport))

For more information, review the documentation topic ["Declarative API for Initial Components"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/82a0fcecc3cb427c91469bc537ebdddf).