# SAPUI5- Add button to list items

Tags: sapui5

I have a list which has customlistitems with buttons. The problem is even when I click on the button it takes only the itemclick event and goes to detail page. What I want is to get a pop up when the button is clicked.

How to differentiate item click event with button click event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please always provide some relevant code snippets. If I understood it correctly you should assign a `press` event to the template of your button. See [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22842857/1969374) for more information about list modes and the corresponding events.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the mode of the list to None like this

```
var list = new sap.m.List({
    mode: sap.m.ListMode.None
});
```

In this manner, the list will to "take over" the selection. However, you need to handle press event of each item.

-D

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using sap.m.Dialog - https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/samples 
this is a pop-up from sapui5 and inside I think you can implement even the navigation stuff.