# How to pass data from one view to another view in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

*Master Details Template*

When click on `Master[list]` it will navigate to detail page with table data, suppose four column are there and an "Add" Button in the last column.
Now what I want is, on click that "Add" button that row data will bind direct in cart view.

I tried using local storage, but how to call local stored data in cart view.

[Cart view is on Master page with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzPLz.png)

[On click cart icon view page is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiHB4.png)

```
onPress: function(evt){
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ 
        a : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[0].mProperties.src,
        b : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[1].mProperties.text,
        c : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[2].mProperties.text,
        d : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[3].mProperties.text 
    })); 
    user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far and try to make your question more concrete.

Comment: I have used local storage concept, but how to call it in cart view                            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
a : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[0].mProperties.src,
b : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[1].mProperties.text,                    c : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[2].mProperties.text,
d : evt.oSource.oParent.mAggregations.cells[3].mProperties.text
}));
user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

Comment: Please edit the question and add this code to it instead of a comment.

Comment: Also see [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22842857/1969374)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are in a Component-based application using a UI5 Router and an ODataModel resp. Service.

You could just pass the id of your table entry onto the detail view via routing:

```
onAddBtnPressed : function(oEv) {
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this),
      oContext = oEv.getSource().getBindingContext("your-model-name"),
      sDetailID = oContext.get("your-id-prop-name");
  oRouter.navTo("detail", {
    detailID: sDetailID
  })
}
```

from routing.config.routes:

```
{
  "pattern": "detail/{detailID}",
  "name": "detail",
  "target": "detail"
}
```

**Note**: `{param}` marks a parameter as mandatory while `:param:` is used for an optional parameter.

In your Detail.controller.js register a listener on routePatternMatched and implement it like this:

```
onRoutePatternMatched: function(oEv) {
  var sDetailID = oEv.getParameter("arguments").detailID;
  // create binding context on detail view
  this.getView().bindElement({
    "/YourDetailSet('"+ sDetailID +'")"
    model: "your-model-name"
  })
  // all the bindings in your detail view will no be relative to the above binding context.
}
```